# How to format only changed line instead of the whole file in Intelijj IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij format complete file when I use <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Atl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for from menu code-> Reformat Code. This generates whole diff in git commit. I want to format only the code I have changed not the whole file. How can I do it?

Comment: While Ersoy provides maybe a good answer, the code format of the UNCHAGED code should be already correct (comply with the coding standard you have set) such that a reformat of the full code will indeed only create changes in the new lines. That is: Intelli-Js Code Format Setup should be consists with your coding style standards).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to select the portion of the code you'd like to format (in your case, the edited code). And then press `Ctrl+Alt+L`.

You can find more info [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat_code).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Correct answer should be select the edited code and then Ctrl+Alt+I . Still I accept your answer as correct one. Coz, you pointed me to the correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

If your file is under version control, another option could be selecting `Only VCS changed text` from the Reformat dialog modal.

As it stated in the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-file-dialog.html)

> If this checkbox is selected, then reformatting will apply only to the files that have been changed locally, but not yet checked in to the repository.
> This checkbox is only available for the files under version control.

[image: reformat dialog]

Comment: how can this be set as default behavior for CTRL+ALT+L without the dialog?

Comment: @oriadam (i am not sure whether i get it right) there is an existing feature request for this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5806 other than that some people use https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions this plugin for it.

Answer (score 12):

In case this is helpful to anyone, there is an option in PhpStorm under "Tools > Actions on Save" that allows you to reformat code on save. The option allows you to only reformat changed lines.

This effectively allows you to reformat changed lines only by pressing `cmd + s`

[image: Reformat Code on Save option]

Comment: I have a problem with this solution. It also reformats lines which I did not touched... quite annoying

Comment: @thmasker If you change the option in the screenshot to only format "Changed lines", this shouldn't happen.

Comment: that's the thing, it happens

Comment: Indeed, it does happens to me too, and definitely really annoying.

Comment: it actually change whole file when you have single change on the file. i think is a bug

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, is this bug fixed?

Comment: After upgrading to 2023.1.4 (community) am not facing the issue. I think it is fixed. Kindly check once.